# Opera Mini bitmap fonts

Tags: opera

I am developing a website with several Indic languages on it. I'm making extensive use of the font-family feature of `CSS`, which is of course not supported by `Opera Mini`.

The workaround is that users can enable *bitmap fonts for complex scripts* in their about:config screen on `Opera Mini`. However, I would rather do something from the server side rather than count on users to know how to do that.

I could detect if the client is running `Opera Mini` (see [here](https://dev.opera.com/articles/opera-mini-and-javascript/#detectingmini)) and potentially pop up something alerting the user that they need to turn on that feature. However, if the feature is already enabled it would annoy the user if they kept being reminded to do something they've already done.

I can think of two possible solutions:

1. A way to detect if the *bitmap fonts* feature has been enabled and act accordingly.
2. A way to force Opera Mini to use *bitmap fonts* for rendering a particular site.

I'm thinking that this is perhaps better submitted as a feature request to the Opera Mini developers, but perhaps such a way to accomplish these things already exists. Anybody knows?